# trycatch crashes when error has two messages in R purrr map

Tags: r, try-catch, purrr

The following code works as expected:

```
map(c(1,2,3),
    function(x){
      record <-tryCatch({
        completed <- read_csv("http://example/com/madeup.csv")
        return(completed)
      },
      error=function(cond) {
        message("CAUGHT", cond)
        return(0)
      })
    })
```

But if I add another message command to the error part of trycatch it errors out

```
map(c(1,2,3),
    function(x){
      record <-tryCatch({
        completed <- read_csv("http://example/com/madeup.csv")
        return(completed)
      },
      error=function(cond) {
        message("CAUGHT")
        message(cond)
        return(0)
      })
    })

CAUGHT
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `open.connection()`:
! Could not resolve host: example
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Called from: signal_abort(cnd, .file)
```

Putting this trycatch in a for loop works fine:

```
for(x in c(1,2,3)){
    record <-tryCatch({
        completed <- read_csv("http://example/com/madeup.csv")
        return(completed)
      },
      error=function(cond) {
        message("CAUGHT")
        message(cond)
        return(0)
      })
}
```

I think that this used to work for map, have I missed a change?

Comment: Nothing to do with two calls to `message()`, but you need to use `message(as.character(cond))` as it doesn't seem to be automatically coerced in this case.

Comment: ah, good spot, I didn't realise `message("CAUGHT", cond)` did this coercion automatically

Comment: interestingly this isn't an issue in a forloop. Why does map make the message(cond) error out?